# Is there anyway to track which awards have been earned per level?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I'm attempting to finish some of the achievements that require particular awards to be earned on all the levels.

Is there anyway to track how close I am to earning a particular achievement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click on the crystal in your tavern it will bring up a window showing the statistics for the particular levels. Across the top are the levels of difficulty, by clicking on the name you can see which badges you have earned on each level.

Edit: Aim at the crystal, use the "View your statistics button" F by default.

Comment: I'm clicking the ribbon, but the award screen isn't coming up. It is the screen you use to pick levels, right?

Comment: No, I believe you have to press another button at the crystal(F I think) to bring up statistics.